# Camera mode change to video with Zenmuse XT2 fails with error: Not Support

Tags: java, android, dji-sdk

When I call:

```
camera.setMode(SettingsDefinitions.CameraMode.RECORD_VIDEO, null);
```

using the Zenmuse XT2 I get the error: Not Support

I have checked if the camera is storing a photo as I heard elsewhere that you cannot change mode while that is in progress, it is not.

The code works fine using the Zenmuse XT and Zenmuse X3 cameras. Is there an alternative procedure to use for the XT2?

Comment: have you tried `SettingsDefinitions.CameraMode.MEDIA_DOWNLOAD`? "set the mode of "media.download " when photo storage is false." according to this report https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-Android/issues/173

Comment: similar code in `Mobile-SDK` docs show a `switchCameraMode()` method that may be helpful https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-Doc/blob/d38e106dda2ba74c24eb95facbeec58c66ac7c8b/source/cn/android-tutorials/index.md#switching-camera-mode

Comment: @davedwards It seems switchCameraMode() is a user-created method which checks for the existence of the camera object before calling setMode().

Comment: please upgrade the firmware of xt2